# Sale an existing s3 file on Drupal commerce

Tags: amazon-s3, drupal-commerce

I have installed commerce_file module and all of the dependence modules.
I can create a product of file download, if i upload the file to the server.
But what i would like to do is to sale an existing files that are already exist on amazon S3 server.

How do i do this (without writing my own code...)?

Answer (score 0):

O.K if someone else will run in to this issue, the problem was a meter of:

1. get into the commerce_file field settings in the product type I wanted to attach the s3 file to.
2. Under "FILE SOURCES" settings - "Amazon S3 reference"

Leave a comment if you have any question about this issue